# Writing a code generator that refers to existing Java classes

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, dsl

I'm trying to evaluate different approaches to have some code in our Java project generated automatically from definitions in a domain-specific language while building the project. I have manually written a code generator or two in the past but I have no experience with existing code generation frameworks. We have not yet decided whether to use such a framework or build the generator by hand.

I need help with a conceptual problem; I would like to understand **how a code generator can be built which allows the DSL to refer to existing (hand-written) Java classes, methods and fields**. It should be possible to refer to classes that are in the same compilation unit (e.g. Maven project) as the generated Java classes. This means that those hand-written classes cannot be compiled before the code generator is run and the code generator would have to look at Java source files in addition to everything required to be on the *classpath* for compiling those classes.

How do existing frameworks handle such cases, if at all? Do they parse the Java source files themselves or do they re-use some machinery of the Java compiler?

I think this is the same problem that any (non-dynamic) non-Java language targeting the JVM faces, if it allows its own code to reference Java classes and vice-versa in the same compilation units. Maybe it is helpful to look at how those compilers work, unless they circumvent `javac` by also include a Java compiler themselves.

There are multiple reasons why the code generator needs access to the classes in the Java files of the same compilation unit:

- I would like to provide semantics similar to those in Java where I can `import <package>.*` and then use the names of those classes without fully qualifying the name of each of them.
- I would like to reject code in the DSL if it refers to symbols that don't exists or don't meet some required criteria.
- There will be cases where I want to generate code that depends on the members of a class or the signatures of methods. An example would be to automatically generate a decorator or builder or implement an interface but where the base class or interface is not generated by the code generator.
- I may want to use the type information of referenced symbols in the generate code. e.g. generating different code depending on the signature of a method.

Our project uses Maven. I'm interested in general approaches to solving these problems but information or examples that apply to Maven are greatly appreciated.

How can I extend Java with a DSL that allows the DSL compiler to refer to external Java elements (classes, methods, fields)?

Comment: If the problem is "reference a Java class/method/field", why can't you simply use a fully qualified name?

Comment: @IraBaxter I completely missed to explain that. I added a list of reasons why I need access to the type information of members, the list of members of a class and the list of classes in a package (in order of decreasing importance).

Comment: You might want to submit this question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead of taking a beating here.

Comment: @IraBaxter SR.SE is for software recommendations. This question isn't calling for third-party software, it's asking about methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Actually unclear what you're asking, furthermore this question is more theoretical, than programmic.

In any case, from my experience of own DSL implementation, there isn't any problem use `java` `classloaders` for dynamically access to new generated and compiled java classes. Also, if you are using `maven`, so all dependencies with production scope must be loaded in main classloader and be available to load them using `reflection`.

Here are some useful links:

- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-java/the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: You are missing part of my question; I want to reference Java classes that are not yet compiled from the DSL code. The Java classloader can only load classes that are already compiled as it needs access to the byte code and not just the inheritance graph and method/field signatures, which is all the DSL compiler would need.

Comment: @Feuermurmel I don't see any problem with this issue: just include sources of this file in compilation unit. Compiler will link them together and compile witout troubles.

Comment: I would like to reference symbols that are in the _same_ compilation unit as the code that is generated from the DSL code. Compilers for languages like Scala or Kotlin can process mixed code that references each other and I wanted to see whether there's a general approach to doing that without re-implementing part of a Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Do not parse java programs, use compiled classes instead. The referenced classes can be written in different languages, including other DSL - the only common denominator is class file format.

This cause a problem of circular dependency, when a java program refers to a DSL program and at the same time that DSL program refers back to java program. Possible solutions are:

- do not analyse any other programs while converting DSL to Java. All possible errors would be reporting while compiling generated java code
- redirect references to common interfaces, thus breaking dependency loop